# Spawning SkShapeNodes with NSTimer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nstimer, skshapenode

I am creating a game in sprite kit and I would like to spawn enemies on the screen at certain intervals. As of right now, the code I run crashes as soon as the timer is supposed to preform its action, giving me the error message Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). Here is the code that I am trying to enact.

```
        func randomElement() -> SKShapeNode! {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfEnemies.count)))
        return arrayOfEnemies[index] as! SKShapeNode
    }

    func randomElement2() -> SKShapeNode! {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfEnemies2.count)))
        return arrayOfEnemies2[index] as! SKShapeNode
    }

    func randomElement3() -> SKShapeNode! {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfEnemies3.count)))
        return arrayOfEnemies3[index] as! SKShapeNode
    }

    func randomElement4() -> SKShapeNode! {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfEnemies4.count)))
        return arrayOfEnemies4[index] as! SKShapeNode
    }

    let addEnemy = randomElement()

    let addEnemy2 = randomElement2()

    let addEnemy3 = randomElement3()

    let addEnemy4 = randomElement4()


    func addAllEnemies() {
        self.addChild(addEnemy)
        self.addChild(addEnemy2)
        self.addChild(addEnemy3)
        self.addChild(addEnemy4)
    }

    var Enemy = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector(addAllEnemies()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

At the start of the game, 4 of the random enemies spawn and do what they are supposed to do. 3 seconds later, when the timer is set to restart the function, the game crashes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a game with Sprite-kit, the best way to integrate Timers in your project would be to use SKAction instead of NSTimer

```
SKAction.waitForDuration(some value)
```

If you want it to repeat itself forever you can also use

```
SKAction.repeatActionForever(your action)
```

After that, you can create a custom function that is called when the timer ends through SKAction.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recreate the enemy each time you want to add it. Creating them in the method and making a copy should fix it for you.

```
func addAllEnemies() {

    let addEnemy = randomElement().copy()
    let addEnemy2 = randomElement2().copy()
    let addEnemy3 = randomElement3().copy()
    let addEnemy4 = randomElement4().copy()
    self.addChild(addEnemy)
    self.addChild(addEnemy2)
    self.addChild(addEnemy3)
    self.addChild(addEnemy4)

}
```

Hopefully that helps.